# How to let ApplicationWindow lower than its parent?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm using js in qml to create a `ApplicationWindow`:

```
var component = Qt.createComponent("Page.qml");
var w = component.createObject(globalRoot);
w.show();
```

The `globalRoot` is also an `ApplicationWindow`, after I created the sub window. I found I can't let the `globalRoot` window above the sub window I created.

I searched the document but found nothing saying about this. How can I let those two windows behave like normal windows in Windows?

Comment: Look to the [`Window`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#details) description: the dynamically created `Window` is transient for the `globalRoot` and thus dependent on it. Documentation proposes the usage of `QtObject` for independent `Window`s. It seems to me that passing `null` to `createObject` does the trick. I wouldn't be wrong but I remember there was some kind of limitation about the possible top level containers.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Yes you are right, plz post your answer.

Comment: I remembred correctly. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27589432/2538363) answer the `null` approach can work *BUT* it is unstable. Simple examples might work but you can experience very strange issues, like in the linked answer. Follow the advices (and links) in the mentioned answer. Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23648698/2538363) answer can be helpful.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo I got it, many thanks !